# HttpClient and ReadAsAsync<T>() extension method

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

So I'm starting up a new .Net 4.0 project and will be doing some work with a public API.  I'm planning on using the Microsoft HttpClient class so I installed the latest stable version of the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package (version 2.2.13).  I'm looking at some POC code that a coworker put together, also using a NuGet package for HttpClient and notice that there's code like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAync("/uri").Result;

DomainType result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DomainType>().Result;
```

In my project, after adding the reference to the Microsoft.Net.Http package, when I try to write similar code, I noticed that HttpResponseMessage doesn't have a `ReadAsAsync<T>()` method.  After doing some digging in my coworker's POC solution, it looks like `ReadAsAsync<T>()` is actually an extension method in the `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly.  In this POC solution, there's a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting, however it's pulling this file from the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`.

My question is, is there a better solution to getting access to this extension method than referencing this assembly from my local ASP.Net installation?  My concern is that this is going to cause a problem on our CI server since it's not likely to have ASP.Net installed.  I guess I could copy System.Net.Http.Formatting to a Lib directory in my solution but I'm hoping there's a better option such as another NuGet package I'm missing that would give me this assembly.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the assembly, (extension method or not is irrelevant) one way or another you need to reference it and make sure it's included when you build. The `C:\Program Files...` path shouldn't be important on the server where it's deployed.

Comment: Right, thanks, however I do understand how assembly references work.  The problem with the C:\Program Files... is that path isn't likely to exist in our CI server.  So the way I see it, I can either copy that assembly to a Lib directory under my solution so that gets added to source control and will be retrieved by CI when it builds the solution, or, preferably, find some other NuGet package that has the assembly in it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's part of the WebAPI client libraries package.  Install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package.

Comment: Does this work with .NET Core? I have added this nuget package. But it still doesn't work. Am i missing some using statement?

Comment: I installed it but nothing changed